Does Annotate Composition create a one-use scroll?
Annotate Composition lets you create a scroll that can then be read by anyone to cast your composition spell for you.
When the scroll is used in such a way, can it still be used during subsequent turns or does it disintegrate?
The description suggests the former but it permits a dangerous combo where your familiar always spams Dirge of Doom at no cost.

One-Time Use
Annotate Composition creates a special scroll:

You spend 10 minutes and 1 Focus Point to transpose a composition spell on a special scroll that you or another creature can later activate.

meaning we have to use the rules for scrolls, which state:

The spell on a scroll can be cast only once, and the scroll is destroyed as part of the casting.

The "deactiviation" clause of Annotate Composition (which I'm assuming is where you are reading the implication the scroll remains) is almost certainly there so that you have of getting back your locked up Focus Points, which are very important to a Bard, while also preventing you from loading up on these over many days.
The rules for rule interpretation mention that, when it comes to ambiguous rules:

If one version is too good to be true, it probably is.

Additionally, given the Specific over General principle, if the scroll was meant to persist (and thus be an exception to the rules for scrolls), we would expect that to be mentioned clearly, since it's a deviation from the norm (and hardly an obscure norm at that). Given the lack of specific overrider here, we should default to the normal rules:

While some special rules may also state the normal rules to provide context, you should always default to the normal rules even if effects don’t specifically say to.

